# usage of tooltip in C#.net 4.0

Tags: c#, tooltip

My question is whether is it possible to fetch some values from database to show as a `tooltip`, for particular values in `listBox`?

Scenario:

I have few items in `listBox`,say for example red, yellow, white.

When i select / bring my mouse arrow / focused near any one of the item , the `tooltip` must display..for example, if red, then `tooltip` should display "primary color", if "yellow" ,then `tooltip` should display "secondary color".

I had stored the "primary color","secondary color",.. , the `tooltip` that must be showed when focused, in the database.

My question is whether is it possible to fetch some values from database to show as a `tooltip`, for particular values in `listbox`?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to read a database? How to set a tooltip?

Comment: windows form application

Comment: how to set the tooltip text from the database based on focused item in windows form?

Comment: You have problem getting data from database or showing tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by hooking this method to mouse move event of your listbox

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

private void onMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if(sender is ListBox)
   {  
      ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
      Point point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
      int hoverIndex = listBox.IndexFromPoint(point);
      if(hoverIndex >= 0 && hoverIndex < listBox.Items.Count)
      {
         ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
         tt.SetToolTip(listBox, "GetYourCustomTooltiphere");
      } 
   }    
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  Which was "is it possible to fetch some values from database"?  You'll, somehow, will have to demonstrate an of-course-you-can answer.

Comment: @HansPassant i guess his question relates to showing the custom tooltip (other than what is already displayed in the text) rather than fetching data.

Comment: @ShamilEvil added in the answer.

Comment: @Ehsan Ullah, sorry, nothing happened..no tooltip was displayed    private void listBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {             if (sender is ListBox)
            {
                ListBox listBox = (ListBox)sender;
                Point point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                int hoverIndex = listBox.IndexFromPoint(point);
                if (hoverIndex >= 0 && hoverIndex < listBox.Items.Count)
                {
                    ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
           tt.SetToolTip(listBox, GetYourCustomTooltiphere");
                }
            }

        }

Comment: @ShamilEvil  Place your debugger here and see if the above code is hit during debugging?