# How to take the value from a column while hover the mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, hover

I have 2 grids in a form. One grid is filled with some Students info. And I want that when I put the Mouse over the dataGridview1, to show the other gridview like a Popup or something like that, and populate the other datagridview with informatin based on the Name column.

I did the part where the grid shows as a popup and follows the mouse. Also when it leaves the grid it will disappear:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da2;
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name, Surname, City"+ 
                             "FROM tblStudents2" +
                             "WHERE Name = **what to write here**", con);

    da2.Fill(dt2);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView2.Visible = false;
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView2.Visible = true;
    dataGridView2.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X-100, MousePosition.Y-100);
}
```

I just want to ask you, what to write i the SQL Statement, at the part: **WHERE Name='*_*__*_*'** ??

I want that when the Mous is over the first Row, to take the Name (column index 1) and populate the other datagrid.

I hope you understand me :(

****EDITED
Here is my code after going through the Code Of Ehsan... It workes almost. The problem is it doesn't Repopulate the grid after moving the mouse to the next row!! Butif I leave the DataGrid, and put the mouse to the other Row, it shows me the ifnormation of this row. How to make something lik a refresh grid after moving the mouse to the next row??

```
 public void LoadGridi2()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da2;
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name, Surname, City FROM tblMentori WHERE Name = '" + dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'", con);

        da2.Fill(dt2);

        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
    }
    private void dataGridView1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       LoadGridi2();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.Visible = false;
    }
    DataGridViewRow row;
    private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView2.Visible = true;
        dataGridView2.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X - 100, MousePosition.Y - 100);

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771973/usage-of-tooltip-in-c-net-4-0/17772017#17772017

Comment: @EhsanUllah, your answer is for a listbox... is it the same as for a datagrid ?

Comment: Yes the idea is same, anyways i have posted the answer here for datagrid

Answer (score 1):

You should do this. Bind to the CellMouseMove event of grid.

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
             DataGridViewRow row = DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
             SqlDataAdapter da2;
             DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
             da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name, Surname, City FROM tblStudents2 WHERE Name = '" + row["Name"].Value.ToString()+ "'", con);

            da2.Fill(dt2);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
        }
    }
```

and

```
  e.RowIndex
```

is the index you are looking for

Comment: this part doesn't work... invalid argments:  `new Point(dataGridView2.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)));`

Comment: But Ehsan, how to take the index know and put it in the SQl Statemnt in WHERE, at MOUSE HOVER Evenet?

Comment: You can call your method with parameter index and then set that parameter to the where clause

Comment: Sorry bro for taking your time, but I don't know what you mean. I am new in c#. Ho to call the method with parameters in WHERE='"+dataGridview.Rows[this damn index].Cells[1].Value.Tostring()+"'

Comment: when I hover the mouse over a row, it shows me the information on the grid, but if I change the row it still doesn't repopule the Grid!! Only if I leave the Datgrid and then put againg the mouse over the other row

Answer (score 0):

Use `CellMouseMove` event. You can get item which is bound to current row (e.g. some `Person` instance):

```
void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    var person = (Person)grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
    var name = person.Name;
}
```

---

Here is full code (I use label control for simplicity):

```
// this field used to avoid loading data which you already have
private Person currentPerson;

void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0)
    {
        HidePersonDetails();
        return;
    }

    DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    var person = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Person;
    if (person == null)
    {
        HidePersonDetails();
        return;
    }

    var rectangle = grid.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
    var cellLocation = rectangle.Location;
    var detailsLocation = new Point(e.X + cellLocation.X, 
                                    e.Y + cellLocation.Y + rectangle.Height);
    ShowPersonDetails(person, detailsLocation);
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HidePersonDetails();
}

private void ShowPersonDetails(Person person, Point location)
{
    if (currentPerson != person)
    {
        // get data from SQL server
        // set datasource of your details grid
        currentPerson = person;
    }

    label1.Text = person.Name;
    label1.Location = location;
    label1.Show();
}

private void HidePersonDetails()
{
    label1.Hide();
}
```

Comment: e.Rowindex is the index

Comment: @user2478115 `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs` provide both cell and row indexes.